# Any good way to inverse a function?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sketch

I'm guessing that the answer to this is "no," but I'm curious if there is any way to save writing some code by specifying a function to do the opposite of whatever another function does. For example the inverse of:

```
int FW (int in)
{
  int out=2+in;
  Return out
}
```

would be

```
int RV (int in)
{
  int out=in-2;
  Return out
}
```

However, would there be any way to call the inverse of `FW()` if it was a more complicated function that still had one and only one input for each output?

Comment: Ask this question on stackoverflow and use `c` tag .You will get much better answers there

Comment: You could crate a more general function like; MOVE(int in, int direction){}

Comment: @Sniper, this is hardly a C question.  More of a theory question.  Per [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) on wikipedia,  “Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for all possible program-input pairs cannot exist”, providing an easy answer of *No* to the question in its general form, and with more effort probably to the  “one and only one input for each output” subquestion as well. ¶ ATE-ENGE, of course there are lots of ways to get function inverses for *particular* functions, but from Turing's result not in general

Comment: lol! Well if Turing said I can't do it, I suppose I shouldn't try XD

Comment: Now if it could be used to figure out the original two factors multiplied together to produce a big number, then you would be on to something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A function does what it does and that is all. No other function can know what some other function does.

You could write a function that does different things depending on what parameters you pass to it, but that's the closest you can get, and is pretty pointless when you can just write different functions anyway.

Comment: That's what I had thought. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: You can trivially see this to be true: imagine a function which returns 1 if the integer argument is odd, 0 if it is even. It's impossible to reverse this in reality, regardless of what you know about the code and what the code knows about the code.